# Why are 301 redirects intermittently slow or time out in IIS 6?

Tags: iis, iis-6, 301-redirect

I'm no IIS wiz, but I can provide any additional info that might be helpful.

My site uses a 301 redirect to send requests for mysite.com to www.mysite.com. They are two separate sites in IIS. Most of the time it works without issue, but from time to time the redirect will take many seconds. Once I left it alone and it sat for about five minutes before timing out. Hitting refresh almost always causes the redirect to happen instantly as intended. I cannot find a pattern for this behavior, server logs look fine, and it doesn't appear to be happening during high volume times. To my eye it's happening at random. Can anyone suggest a way for me to track down the root of this issue or has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: maybe the other domain has unloaded due to inactivity?